# Can I be threatened with termination for speaking to HR?

Tags: human-resources

I have recently received a CAD or Career Advisement Day from my employer. For those who do not know this term it is basically a disciplinary action taken similar to a write up where the employee who receives it takes a day off work without pay and decides if they are going to continue with the company, then is required to write or sign a letter stating that they understand the nature of their write-up and that they will adhere to all company policies moving forward.

In my case the action that got me the CAD was not true. It was reported that I had thrown paperwork at one of the on-site nurses and then cussed her out before storming out of the office. I know 100% that this never happened but I figured it was maybe a report by medical staff that was blown out of proportion or embellished upon. So I spoke with one of my friends on the nursing staff about it with the intention of figuring out which one of them made the report, finding out what the actual issue was that sparked the report to be made in the first place, and then cleaning up my side of the street and apologizing for whatever discrepancy caused them offense, because I assumed there was SOMETHING that had happened.

It turns out that none of the nurses or medical staff had any idea about this and hadn't filed the report, which means it came from one of my co-workers on shift, and that even the nurses working that shift stated that there was nothing that happened that was remotely close to what the report had stated thus nothing to take offense too. This means that for whatever reason one of my co-workers filed a false report about me with the intention of getting me in trouble. Now I have my ideas about who and why this could have happened but that is not the issue.

The issue I'm having is when I spoke to my boss about this discovery I was told that

1. I should not be speaking to outside agencies ( the nurses are all from another company) about internal disciplinary actions, Which after thinking about it is a reasonable policy that I can understand.
2. That moving forward I was not to press the issue any further.

He said that if I spoke to HR about this that I would be fired. I told him that I don't expect anything to change about the CAD, I just wanted to address the issue that the report was maliciously fabricated with the intent of getting me fired or in trouble somehow by someone within our company.

I believe that constitutes a Hostile Work Environment and while my CAD can still stand, Something needs to be done about the action of a false report deliberately directed at me with intent of creating a hostile work environment. I also believe that it is wrong if not possibly illegal for my employer to tell me that if I speak to HR about this issue he will fire me. I am not sure if it is illegal, I found lots of things relating to discrimination or sexual harassment where it is illegal for employers to retaliate against someone making a claim of that nature. But I don't think my situation falls under harassment and I know it is not discrimination.

I think I should be able to speak with HR about anything without the fear of  termination, so long as the content of what I am speaking isn't something that is grounds to be fired. But bringing it to the attention of my Human Resources that another employee intentionally falsified a report that could have gotten me fired should not be grounds for me getting fired. Should it?

Where could I find out information on my companies policies regarding these sorts of things? I don't know if this helps but I live in Arizona.

Comment: Please try and edit this to introduce some paragraphs and structure; a wall of text is incredibly hard for other people to read and understand.

Comment: You had to ask around before you knew the report was false? Shouldn't you have known that right away, and said so to whoever issued the CAD?

Comment: wall of text, not knowing about the handbook, sounds like someone new to employment. Consider that your own experience and pridefulness might be factors here.

Answer (score 3):

> Can i be threatened with termination for speaking to HR?

Yes, of course. You can be threatened with anything by anybody. The key question here is how to react to the thread.

> I think i should be able to speak with HR about anything without the fear of termination,

Why do you think this? HR's primary role to make sure that the company is compliant with all internal polices and external regulations. They are neither your friend nor are they your enemy. They do their job.

> where could i find out information on my companies policies regarding these sorts of things?

Your company should have a company handbook that's available to all employees. You can't expect your employees to comply with your policies if you don't tell them what your policies are. If you don't know where to find it, just ask HR. That's a perfectly fine question to ask them. You can just tell them you want to read up on current policies, to makes sure that you are compliant.

> i live in Arizona.

Arizona is am at-will state. That means that you can be fired anytime for any reason or no reason at all.

The question you didn't ask:

> What's my best course of action

1. Figure out what your companies policies for disciplinary actions are.
2. Determine if anything that happened is in violation of any policy
3. Figure out what your goals are: keep your job, keep the relationship with your boss intact, expose the reporter, just make the whole thing go away, etc.

Decide your next action based on these steps.

Comment: This is a very important lesson for people to learn. HR is not your friend.

Comment: Yes, but they are not your enemy either . They can be quite useful in the right context

Answer (score 1):

## Human Resources Works for Management

People seem to have an idea that HR is a safe space for employees.  This might be true is a very small number of companies, but usually HR is there to ensure that managers follow the rules when it comes to employee discipline.  But firstly, the job of an HR manager or resource is to be an agent for the company, like every other manager.  The **company** will always be first.  A good HR manager works within this because they realize that good employee relations are good for business. But never expect them to  "take your side" unless you have an issue that breaks a rule, law, or standard.

The first call HR makes after you talk to them about anything contentious is to your manager.  HR is a staff organization, and most HR managers understand this.  Their job is not to get between manager-subordinate relationships, unless specifically tasked with this by the organization.

The result of all this is that in general "going to HR" will just make your boss mad.  And in the US, the boss can usually fire you for any reason, unless you are protected by specific company guidelines around discipline or a union contract.  You will never truly "win" a battle with your boss by involving HR.

Answer (score 1):

> Where could I find out information on my companies policies regarding these sorts of things?

HR can give you this information. You can approach them for it without giving the underlying reason and then make a more informed decision on what to do afterwards.